# Correct xml data type for Payroll hours

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to integrate the Payroll API (USA) but running into challenges posting a Timesheet.
I'm using a JSON to xml parser which is giving me an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Timesheet>
  <EmployeeID>9e246df3-8775-43ee-bc7e-47f5f5896964</EmployeeID>
  <EndDate>2017-10-16T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
  <Hours>43.2000</Hours>
  <StartDate>2017-10-10T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
  <Status>Draft</Status>
</Timesheet>
```

I have no experience with xml APIs but that looks the same as the example code provided. However on the API end the hours I get returned are 0:

```
"Status":"DRAFT","Hours":0,
```

etc...

The Timesheet on the user console end also has 0 hours.
Is there something else I need to be considering here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
I had misinterpreted the API, the "Hours" for a period is the hours calculated by Xero, based on the quantity of pay items provided.
Hopefully this clarifies in case anyone else has same confusion.